# Why is $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geq 1\}$ not type 3 (regular)?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

My book states that the language
$$L_1 = \{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 1\}$$
is of type 2 (context-free) but not of type 3 (regular) since there is no regular grammar to produce it. However, I can't really imagine how this grammar should not be applicable or why it shouldn't be a valid type 3 grammar:
$$S \to aS \mid bS \mid b\,.$$

For my understanding this grammar produces the language in question and also fulfils the type 3 criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S\Rightarrow bS\Rightarrow baS\Rightarrow bab$.

However, $bab$ is not $a^nb^n$ for any $n$.

---

(**Exercise.**) Is the following grammar a grammar for $L_1$?

$S \to Sa \mid Sb \mid a$

Comment: Exercise solution: No it's just the other way around and one can produce aba for instance. :) Thank you!

Comment: Correct! You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar produces every possible string that ends in $b$.

The proof that $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 1\}$ is not regular is standard and can be found in any textbook – use the pumping lemma, Myhill–Nerode or one of the other characterizations of regular languages.